# Pronunciation of "r" in Esperanto

Tags: pronunciation

Is the letter `r` in Esperanto pronounced like `غ` in Arabic? Or like `r` in French?

Comment: Zamenhof was no linguist, and one may only assume a well pronounced _**r**_. Hence more like in slavic languages. Slightly more trilled than the almost soundless r in English.AFAIK there is no written norm in E-o. English is by far not the only language with a weak r pronunciation.

Answer (score 3):

The most common pronunciation that most people strive for is like the *rr* in Spanish (ie, it is trilled).

However in practice many people have difficulty with this and it’s not uncommon to hear the French or English *r*. It doesn’t really pose any problems to understanding. In the official source of Esperanto, The Fundamento, it’s not really clear which pronunciation is actually official, if any, because each translation of it tends to say the *r* is pronounced the same as in the target language. In general as long as the sound is consistent and cleary distinguishable it doesn’t really matter too much how it’s pronounced.

[PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/elparolo/bazaj_reguloj.html) has a more complete description of the pronunciation.

Comment: Hi Neil.  Actually, it's more like the single "r" in Spanish, not the double "r" ("rr").  The double "r" is a longer trill than the single "r".

Comment: @Karlomanio Are you sure? As far as I understand the single _r_ is just a single tap when it’s between vowels in Spanish, whereas the Esperanto _r_ is supposed to be trilled. The IPA letter used in Wikipedia to describe the Spanish pronunciation of _rr_ matches the one used in PMEG.

Comment: What about the arabic `غ`?

Comment: I think the Arabic غ is the same as the French _r_, right? The Esperanto _r_ should be like ر

Comment: The esperanto `r` doesnt sound like `ر` on google translate. Try to hear the word `غ+ر+ي+ب=غريب` on google.

Comment: En la hispana, estas elparola kaj fonema diferencoj inter 'r' kaj 'rr' ('pero' - 'perro'). La Vikipedia artikolo "https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononco_de_Esperanto" komparas ĝin kun la 1-a, ne kun la 2-a. Estas erare kartavi.

Comment: @DominikCornice En PMEG estas “R estu same trema en ĉiaj pozicioj en la vorto. En ekz. rivero la du R estu same elparolataj”. Se ni prononcus la _r_ kiel en _pero_ ni devus fari tion ankaŭ ĉe la komenco de la vorto. Tio vere ne ŝajnas al mia ĝusta. En Vikivortaro la prononco de _pero_ estas /ˈpeɾo/ kaj _paroli_ estas /pa.ˈro.li/. Atentu la malsamajn simbolojn por la _r_.

Comment: @DominikCornice Ekzistas neniu bona kialo por malpermesi diversajn formojn de "r" se ili estas uzataj kaj komprenataj. Prononca elitismo nur igas la lingvon pli malfacila kaj maltaŭga por esti lernata de homoj de malsamaj mondopartoj. Eĉ se oni zorgas pri normo, la Fudamento klare permesas malsamajn formojn.

Comment: @NeilRoberts Mi pensas, ke vi miksas /r/ kaj [r]. En Esperanto ni havas nur unu r-sonon, indikatan per /r/. La vera realigo de tiu sono multe varias: /r/ povas esti [r], [ɾ], [ʀ], [ʁ], ktp. En la hispana oni distingas du r-sonojn, /r/ kaj /ɾ/. En Vikivortaro oni ĉiam skribas la fonemojn, t.e. la sonojn, kiujn la lingvo distingas, ne la sonojn, kiujn la parolanto de la lingvo precize faras. Vidu ekzemple ĉe la nederlanda vorto ‘raar’, kie oni indikas /ˈraːr/ dum multaj diras [ˈʀ̆aɹ] aŭ [ˈɾaːɾ] aŭ ion alian kaj efektive neniu vere diras [ˈraːr] per du plenaj triloj.

Answer (score 3):

A few years ago a student asked Bertilo Wennergren whether it is correct to say *vi ĉiam duobla-ro-igas ĉion* to a person who usually says *vete**rr**o* ([alveolar trill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Alveolar_trill.ogg)) instead of *vete**r**o* ([alveolar tap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Alveolar_tap.ogg)). Although the question was about the use of *ig*, Bertilo thought the student was asking him whether it is correct to say *vete**rr**o* instead of *vete**r**o*, and he answered that it is not too important whether you use a long or a short *r* sound. You can watch it [here](https://youtu.be/aFNoWjTtLVQ?t=41).

Watching that video, it's pretty obvious to me that Bertilo tends to pronounce the *r* like in *vete**r**o*, not *vete**rr**o*. For instance, he says *kolo**r**o*, not *kolo**rr**o*; *Espe**r**anto*, not *Espe**rr**anto*, and so forth. On the other hand, if the word starts with an *r* he tends to pronounce it like in *vete**rr**o*; for example he says ***rr**uĝa*, not ***r**uĝa*. It seems to me that this is a general tendency among many Esperanto speakers, i.e., long *r* if the word starts with it, short *r* otherwise. Just to clarify, by *long r* I mean an [alveolar trill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Alveolar_trill.ogg) and by *short r* I mean an [alveolar tap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Alveolar_tap.ogg). Those are, by the way, the two *r* sounds used in modern Spanish.

In my opinion the multiple ways Esperanto speakers pronounce the *r* challenges the idea of *one letter, one sound*, and I don't mean this is something bad or good, I'm just saying that theory does not always match reality. Listen carefully to how Juliette Ternant pronounces the *r* in [this interview](https://youtu.be/9B9glssaKE4?t=112). She pronounces the words *Espe**r**anto* kaj *mi**r**igita* like *vete**r**o* (i.e. like a Spanish single *r*, which is an alveolar tap), but in the words *g**r**amatikaj* and *p**r**oblemoj* she pronounces it like a French *r*. Nevertheless, her Esperanto sounds to me very good and it flows in a natural and understandable way.

Anyway, if you're interested in learning how to trill/roll the *r* in Esperanto like they do in Spanish, there are lots of tips on YouTube. Don't forget to [have fun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ws0zdkUAh9M) and remember that in Esperanto there are no rules about this, only tendencies and recommendations (*en la praktiko [ĉiu litero varias en sia elparolo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/elparolo/bazaj_reguloj.html)*).

Comment: I interpret the ‘one letter, one sound’-thing as ‘one letter, one phoneme’. So multiple allophones of the same phoneme should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was always annoyed that the Assimil Esperanto (and Latin) courses employed an obvious French 'r'. A lot of Germans and Polish Esperantists also tend to use a guttural 'r'. Personally I don't think it sounds very clear and to some ears a word like e.g. 'ruĝa' might sound like 'luĝa'.
In any case the Fundamento doesn't list 'r' in the alphabet for French/English, though does so for German/Russian which are two different sounds. However to my ear a lot of people who use a guttural 'r', particularly in Dutch/French, make a rasping sound too close to 'ĥ' with no uvular roll in the throat.